# Is CommitAsync() redundant via Confluent .NET Client

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am new to Kafka. I want to know why `CommitAsync()` does NOT do everything on 
[AdvancedConsumer](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/blob/master/examples/AdvancedConsumer/Program.cs)

That is, the result is the same for both when `CommitAsync` is enabled and disabled in terms of remembering offset committed.

**Test 1: Disable `CommitAsync()`**

1 Disable `CommitAsync()` method on `Run_Consume()` like below:

```
public static void Run_Consume(string brokerList, List<string> topics)
       {
         ...
                   //if (msg.Offset % 5 == 0)
                   //{
                   //    Console.WriteLine($"Committing offset");
                   //    var committedOffsets = consumer.CommitAsync(msg).Result;
                   //    Console.WriteLine($"Committed offset: {committedOffsets}");
                   //}
               }
           }
       }
```

2 When `Consumer` starts, it reads all messages from offset 0 to last offset N that have been already read from last session

3 Post new messages to [Producer](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/blob/master/examples/AdvancedProducer/Program.cs) , and Consumer displays new message with offset N+1

4 Kill Consumer

5 Start Consumer, it displays all messages from offset 0 to N+1

**Test 2: Enable `CommitAsync()`**

Step 1 Enable `CommitAsync()` method on `Run_Consume()`

follow the same steps 2 - 5 like above

On both tests, newly started Consumer can still remember the last offset. Thus, Why is `CommitAsync()` stilled called?

Please note the similar issue below:
https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/issues/470#issuecomment-375634009

Comment: Are you using the same group.id for both iterations? Commits are keyed by group,topic,partition, so if you change the group between two runs it will not be able to resume from the last committed offsets.

Comment: same group id. as mentioned on the steps, no changes to group id.